# Can abstract container class and childs be iterable?

Tags: c++, inheritance, interface, iterator

I've created an abstract container class with the following basic functions

```
class AbstractInventory
{
private:
    string name;
public:
    AbstracInventory(string name);
    virtual ~AbstractInventory();
    virtual size_t size() const = 0;
    virtual Stack* stackAt(size_t index) const = 0;
    virtual Stack* &stackAt(size_t index) = 0;
    Stack* operator[](int index) const { return(stackAt(index)); }
    Stack* &operator[](int index) { return(stackAt(index)); }
};
```

As an example this can be one of the derived classes

```
class BasicInventory : public AbstractInventory
{
private:
    vector<Stack*> content;
public:
    BasicInventory(string name, int size, bool sorting = false, ItemFilter* f=nullptr);

    size_t size() const override { return(content.size()); }
    Stack* stackAt(size_t index) const override { return(content[index]);     }
    Stack*& stackAt(size_t index) override { return(content[index]); }
};
```

Now my question is **if its possible to make the abstract interface and it's childs iterable** like a vector or list to use it for example in an foreach loop

Comment: implement `begin` and `end` to return iterators

Comment: It is a bit more complex than that, the base class needs a specialized iterator class, with overloaded operator++, +, distance, begin(), end() that would call virtual functions of the container.   You can probably only safely implement a forward iterator this way.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy Or just use pointers (only if possible of course) :)

Comment: That wouldn't work if the derived class uses a list as its internal container. The choice is obviously left open, otherwise, Mazzefassel would have put the vector  in the base class, hopefully...  Or the contents could be in a file...

Comment: @MichaëlRoy It doesn't matter what, if anything, the derived class uses as its container. `AbstractInventory` mandates element access by index, via `stackAt`; any derived class has no choice but to implement that. An iterator  class would just need to hold `AbstractInventory` pointer and its current index.

Comment: Why are you returning a reference to pointer from your non-const methods? Are you intending to do things like `void stuff(AbstractInventory ai) { ai[10] = new Stack(); ... }`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik yes the reference pointer is intended for you described situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create your own iterator, something like:

```
struct Stack {};

class AbstractInventory;

class AbstractInventoryIterator
{
public:
    using difference_type =  std::ptrdiff_t;
    using value_type = Stack*;
    using pointer = Stack**;
    using reference = Stack*&;
    using iterator_category = std::random_access_iterator_tag;

    AbstractInventoryIterator(AbstractInventory* inv, std::size_t index) : inv(inv), index(index) {}

    AbstractInventoryIterator(const AbstractInventoryIterator&) = default;
    AbstractInventoryIterator& operator =(const AbstractInventoryIterator&) = default;

    bool operator == (const AbstractInventoryIterator& rhs) const { return std::tie(inv, index) == std::tie(rhs.inv, rhs.index); }
    bool operator != (const AbstractInventoryIterator& rhs) const { return !(*this == rhs); }

    reference operator*() const;
    pointer operator->() const { return &operator*(); }

    AbstractInventoryIterator& operator ++() { ++index; return *this; }
    AbstractInventoryIterator& operator --() { --index; return *this; }

    AbstractInventoryIterator operator ++(int) { auto next(*this); ++*this; return next; }
    AbstractInventoryIterator operator --(int) { auto prev(*this); --*this; return prev; }

    AbstractInventoryIterator& operator += (difference_type n) { index += n; return *this; }
    AbstractInventoryIterator& operator -= (difference_type n) { index -= n; return *this; }

    AbstractInventoryIterator operator + (difference_type n) const { auto res(*this); res += n; return res; }
    AbstractInventoryIterator operator - (difference_type n) const { auto res(*this); res -= n; return res; }

    friend AbstractInventoryIterator operator + (difference_type n, AbstractInventoryIterator it) { return it + n; }
    difference_type operator - (const AbstractInventoryIterator& it) const { return index - it.index; }

    reference operator [](difference_type n) const;

    bool operator < (const AbstractInventoryIterator& rhs) const { return rhs - *this > 0; }
    bool operator > (const AbstractInventoryIterator& rhs) const { return rhs < *this; }
    bool operator <= (const AbstractInventoryIterator& rhs) const { return !(rhs < *this); }
    bool operator >= (const AbstractInventoryIterator& rhs) const { return !(*this < rhs); }

private:
    AbstractInventory* inv = nullptr;
    int index = 0;
};

class AbstractInventory
{
private:
    std::string name;
public:
    AbstractInventory(std::string name) : name(name) {}
    virtual ~AbstractInventory() = default;
    virtual std::size_t size() const = 0;
    virtual Stack* stackAt(std::size_t index) const = 0;
    virtual Stack* &stackAt(std::size_t index) = 0;
    Stack* operator[](int index) const { return(stackAt(index)); }
    Stack* &operator[](int index) { return(stackAt(index)); }

    AbstractInventoryIterator begin() { return {this, 0}; }
    AbstractInventoryIterator end() { return {this, size()};}
};


auto AbstractInventoryIterator::operator*() const
-> AbstractInventoryIterator::reference 
{ return inv->stackAt(index); }

auto AbstractInventoryIterator::operator [](difference_type n) const
-> AbstractInventoryIterator::reference
{ return inv->stackAt(index + n); }
```

And equivalent for `const_iterator`.

Comment: Works fine for me but I have one usage question: If I'm inside of an inventory and I want to loop through it in an Inventory class method with a (c++11) foreach, how do I handle the this reference? like `foreach(Stack* s : this) {...}`

Comment: It would be `for (Stack*& s : *this)`